# Delphi XE Jedi 3.45

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-xe, jedi

I'm trying to update the Jedi installation on Delphi XE, but I get an error 
when I'm installing the JCL 2.3 Build 4197 (Jedi 3.45).

```
jclOtaUtils.pas(1311) Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ActivePlatformName'
```

The reason I was updating was because of the `jvclHIDController`, when I add 
it to a form and run it on Windows 7 64bit I get an error "invalid pointer 
operation".

I was able to install the Jedi 3.45 on my Delphi 2007 and found that I still 
get the error using the `jvclHIDController`.

Thanks  for any help.

Comment: Is it possible you had your project files opened by Delphi XE2 and upgraded to XE2 by accident? (ActivePlatformName could be a property in the .dproj files that is specific to XE2.)  I believe there is an option to regenerate project files during JVCL installation.

Comment: You should have googled that error first - that was a problem that already got fixed. See http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=5743

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did google it for several days, but I entered Jedi in the search not JCL.

Comment: If you finally found the solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. It can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at Stefan Glienke's comment